# How to quickly switch .tex-file by passing arguments to filename?

Tags: macros, external-files, strings, arguments, parameters

For example

I have two TeX Projects with a similar filename structure:

[image]

The master.tex has a structure like this:

```
\input{preamble.tex} % <- \bibliography{Projekt_A_Literature} in preamble

% ...

\begin{document}

% ...

    \include{chapter/Projekt_A_cp1.tex}
    \include{chapter/Projket_A_cp2.tex}
    \include{chapter/Projekt_A_cp3.tex}

% ...

\end{document}
```

the purpose is:  I can easily and quickly change filegroup of chapters to input.

```
\include{chpater/Project_A_cp1.tex}        \include{chpater/Project_B_cp1.tex}
\include{chpater/Project_A_cp2.tex}  ==>   \include{chpater/Project_B_cp2.tex} 
\include{chapter/Project_A_cp3.tex}        \include{chpater/Project_B_cp3.tex}
```

a simple but not elegant approach is:

```
\newcommand{\prjindex}{A} $ or \def\prjindex{A}
%...
\begin{document}
  \include{chpater/Project_\prjindex_cp1.tex}
  \include{chpater/Project_\prjindex_cp2.tex}
  \include{chpater/Project_\prjindex_cp3.tex}    
\end{document}
```

the question of this solution is, if I compile not in the master TeX file， it gives errors like

> Undefined control sequence ....{Project_\prjindex_Literature.tex}.

So I came here for a more elegant solution

Comment: In my answer I implemented a routine `\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined` which extracts `\prjindex` from the current `\jobname` in case it is not already defined. This works out as long as one does not use LaTeX's jobname-option for having the jobname deviate from the name of the TeX file in use for initiating compilation. Probably you can include that routine (and calling it) into your `preamble.tex`.  That routine does nothing in case `\prjindex` is already defined.  Therefore within `master.tex` you can define `\prjindex` _before_ inputting `preamble.tex`.  [...more in my next comment...]

Comment: Therefore within `master.tex` you can define `\prjindex` _before_ inputting `preamble.tex`. Now let's look at the scenario of compiling one of your `Projekt_[x]_[y].tex`-files: If compiling one of your `Projekt_[x]_[y].tex`-files leads to inputting `\preamble.tex`, then `\prjindex` will not yet be defined at the time of loading `preamble.tex` and therefore the routine `\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined ` will define `\prjindex` for you. (I used `[x]` as placeholder for `A`/`B`... I used `[y]` as placeholder for `cp1`/`cp2`/... .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need a "mechanism" for autodetecting `\prjindex` in situations where a definition of `\prjindex` is not provided "by hand".

---

Preliminary remarks:

**Usually** the expansion of the primitive `\jobname` forms the name of that file (without extension) which was used for initiating compilation.

E.g., if you compile a project whose main file is `testfile.tex` via the commandline
`latex testfile.tex`
, the primitive `\jobname` will expand to the phrase `testfile`.
Character-tokens in phrases delivered by `\jobname` will always be of category code 12(other) while spaces will always be of category code 10(space).

The phrase `testfile` that comes from expanding `\jobname` will be used for

- creating the .log-file: The .log-file will be named `testfile.log`.
- creating the main .aux-file: That will be named `testfile.aux`.
- creating the .toc-file holding data for the table of contents: That will be named `testfile.toc`.
- creating the .lof-file holding data for the list of figures: That will be named `testfile.lof`.
- creating the .lot-file holding data for the list of tables: That will be named `testfile.lot`.
- etc.

But with most nowadays TeX distributions you can have (La)TeX **deviate from the usual way of handling things**:

With most nowadays TeX distributions you can at the commandline provide a commandline-option (the `‑‑jobname`-option) which lets you change what phrase `\jobname` will deliver.

E.g., if you compile a project whose main file is `testfile.tex` via the commandline
`latex --jobname=foobar testfile.tex`
, the primitive `\jobname` will expand to the phrase `foobar`.

In this case the phrase `foobar` that comes from expanding `\jobname` will be used for

- creating the .log-file: The .log-file will be named `foobar.log`.
- creating the main .aux-file: That will be named `foobar.aux`.
- creating the .toc-file holding data for the table of contents: That will be named `foobar.toc`.
- creating the .lof-file holding data for the list of figures: That will be named `foobar.lof`.
- creating the .lot-file holding data for the list of tables: That will be named `foobar.lot`.
- etc.

**With my suggestion below it is a requrement that LaTeX handles things** in the **usual way**, i.e., things are to be compiled **without** providing some **`‑‑jobname`-option**.

**Therefore my suggestion below is not be suitable for people who use such (online-)LaTeX-platforms/TeX-editors/user-interfaces where under the hood things are configured to make use of the `‑‑jobname`-option.**

---

In case

1. the names of all those files during whose compilation the definition of `\prjindex` is to be "autodetected" (as it will not be defined "by hand") are of pattern `Projekt_⟨#1⟩_⟨#2⟩.tex`— `⟨#1⟩` both denoting the project and not being empty and not containing underscores (`_`)—

, and

2. calling latex for "standalone compiling" files during whose compilation the definition of `\prjindex` is to be "autodetected" always takes place **without** invoking the `‑‑jobname`-option (which implies that the expansion of the `\jobname`-primitive forms the name of that file (without extension) which was used for initiating compilation)

, I can offer a macro `\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined` which acts as follows:

In case the macro `\prjindex` is already defined, it does nothing.

In case the macro `\prjindex` is not defined, it checks whether the expansion of the `\jobname`-primitive is of pattern `Projekt_⟨#1⟩_⟨#2⟩`. If it is not of that pattern, an error-message will be triggerd. If it is of that pattern, it will be examined whether `⟨#1⟩` will be empty. If this is the case, an error-message will be triggered. If this is not the case, the macro `\prjindex` will be defined to expand to `⟨#1⟩`.

I cannot make a decision whether that routine is of use to you because you did not reveal in all too much detail how that part of the file-structure of your project is organized which makes it possible to compile the single `Projekt_⟨#1⟩_⟨#2⟩.tex`-files both "standalone" and when invoked from a master tex-file via `\input` or `\include`.

In case all project-files somehow share the same preamble, you can probably make this routine available to all project-files via that preamble.

Probably you can include that routine (and the call to it) into your `preamble.tex.` That routine does nothing in case `\prjindex` is already defined.
Therefore

- within `master.tex` you can define `\prjindex` **before** inputting `preamble.tex`.
- the scenario of standalone-compiling one of your `Projekt_⟨#1⟩_⟨#2⟩.tex`-files leads to inputting `\preamble.tex` while `\prjindex` is not yet defined, which in turn leads to the routine `\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined` "autodetecting" and defining `\prjindex` for you by examining the result of the expansion of `\jobname`.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%========Code for \GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined=========
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\prjprephrase{Projekt_}%
\def\prjpostphrase{_}%
% \jobname delivers everything but the space (which will be of catcode 10) 
% with catcode 12(other). Therefore "sanitizing" is needed for turning
% everything but the space into catcode 12(other):
\@onelevel@sanitize\prjprephrase
\@onelevel@sanitize\prjpostphrase
\newcommand\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined{%
    \@ifundefined{prjindex}{%
      \expandafter\GetPrjindexCheckPattern\jobname$#1#2$&%
    }{}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\GetPrjindexCheckPattern{%
    \def\GetPrjindexCheckPattern##1#1##2#2##3$##4&{%
      \GetPrjindexPatternfork
      &##4&{\expandafter\GetPrjindexExtractfrompattern\jobname$}%
      &#1#2$&{%
        \GenericError{(\string\prjindex)\space}{%
          Error on input line \the \inputlineno:\MessageBreak
          \string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space cannot extract the\MessageBreak
          \string\prjindex\space from \string\jobname's expansion.\MessageBreak
          (\string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space is defined\MessageBreak
           \space somewhere in this document.)\@gobble
        }{Have a look at the comments in this document.}%
        {%
          \string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space can extract the \string\prjindex\MessageBreak
          from \string\jobname's expansion only in case \string\jobname's expansion is\MessageBreak
          of pattern\MessageBreak
          \@spaces #1\string####1#2\string####2\MessageBreak
          while \string####1 is not empty.\MessageBreak
          If this is the case, the expansion of \string\prjindex\space will be \string####1.\MessageBreak
          \string####1 will not contain underscores (\string_).\MessageBreak
          \string####2 can contain underscores.\MessageBreak
        }%
      }%
      &&&&%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\GetPrjindexPatternfork{%
    \def\GetPrjindexPatternfork##1&#1#2$&##2##3&&&&{##2}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\GetPrjindexExtractfrompattern{%
    \def\GetPrjindexExtractfrompattern#1##1#2##2${%
      \ifx\relax##1\relax
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
      {%
        \GenericError{(\string\prjindex)\space}{%
          Error on input line \the \inputlineno:\MessageBreak
          \string\prjindex\space is empty.\MessageBreak
          (\string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space is defined\MessageBreak
           \space somewhere in this document.)\@gobble
        }{Have a look at the comments in this document.}%
        {%
          \string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space can extract the \string\prjindex\MessageBreak
          from \string\jobname's expansion only in case \string\jobname's expansion is\MessageBreak
          of pattern\MessageBreak
          \@spaces #1\string####1#2\string####2\MessageBreak
          while \string####1 is not empty.\MessageBreak
          If this is the case, the expansion of \string\prjindex\space will be \string####1.\MessageBreak
          \string####1 will not contain underscores (\string_).\MessageBreak
          \string####2 can contain underscores.\MessageBreak
        }%
      }%
      {\newcommand*\prjindex{##1}}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\prjprephrase\expandafter}%
\expandafter{\prjpostphrase}%
%%=====End of code for \GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined=====

\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined

\show\prjindex

\begin{document}
Some document
\end{document}
```

By the way: For testing the routine I saved the example above as `test.tex` and compiled it, invoking the `‑‑jobname`-option with different values.

Compiling via the command `latex test.tex` yielded as expected:

```
! Error on input line 80:
(\prjindex) \GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined cannot extract the
(\prjindex) \prjindex from \jobname's expansion.
(\prjindex) (\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined is defined
(\prjindex)  somewhere in this document.)

Have a look at the comments in this document.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.80 \GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined

? 
> \prjindex=undefined.
l.82 \show\prjindex
```

This was expected as in this case `\jobname` expanded to `test` which is not of pattern
`Projekt_⟨#1⟩_⟨#2⟩`.

Compiling via the command `latex ‑‑jobname=Projekt_A_4  test.tex` yielded as expected:

```
\prjindex=macro:
->A.
l.82 \show\prjindex
```

(You would get the same when the example was saved as `Projekt_A_4.tex` and compiled via the command `latex Projekt_A_4.tex`.)

Compiling via the command `latex ‑‑jobname=Projekt_B_4 test.tex` yielded as expected:

```
\prjindex=macro:
->B.
l.82 \show\prjindex
```

(You would get the same when the example was saved as `Projekt_B_4.tex` and compiled via the command `latex Projekt_B_4.tex`.)

Compiling via the command `latex ‑‑jobname=Projekt_JohannGambolputty_12345 test.tex` yielded as expected:

```
\prjindex=macro:
->JohannGambolputty.
l.82 \show\prjindex
```

(You would get the same when the example was saved as `Projekt_JohannGambolputty_12345.tex` and compiled via the command `latex Projekt_JohannGambolputty_12345.tex`.)

By the way:

Sometimes I organize my project-files as follows:

Preamble.tex

```
% Check whether the \documentclass-command was already invoked.
% If so, increment \inputlevel and stop inputting.
% If not so, don't stop imputting and thus do all the
% preamble-stuff, inclusive defining \inputlevel:
\expandafter\ifx\csname @twoclasseserror\endcsname\documentclass
  \xdef\inputlevel{\number\numexpr\inputlevel+1\relax}%
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
\documentclass{article}%
% 
\newcommand*\inputlevel{1}%
\global\let\inputlevel=\inputlevel
%
% Whatsoever preamble-commands, etc.
%
% Here you can also place the code for defining \GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined
% and then invoke it for defining \prjindex:
%
%%========Code for \GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined=========
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\prjprephrase{Projekt_}%
\def\prjpostphrase{_}%
% \jobname delivers everything but the space (which will be of catcode 10) 
% with catcode 12(other). Therefore "sanitizing" is needed for turning
% everything but the space into catcode 12(other):
\@onelevel@sanitize\prjprephrase
\@onelevel@sanitize\prjpostphrase
\newcommand\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined{%
    \@ifundefined{prjindex}{%
      \expandafter\GetPrjindexCheckPattern\jobname$#1#2$&%
    }{}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\GetPrjindexCheckPattern{%
    \def\GetPrjindexCheckPattern##1#1##2#2##3$##4&{%
      \GetPrjindexPatternfork
      &##4&{\expandafter\GetPrjindexExtractfrompattern\jobname$}%
      &#1#2$&{%
        \GenericError{(\string\prjindex)\space}{%
          Error on input line \the \inputlineno:\MessageBreak
          \string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space cannot extract the\MessageBreak
          \string\prjindex\space from \string\jobname's expansion.\MessageBreak
          (\string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space is defined\MessageBreak
           \space somewhere in this document.)\@gobble
        }{Have a look at the comments in this document.}%
        {%
          \string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space can extract the \string\prjindex\MessageBreak
          from \string\jobname's expansion only in case \string\jobname's expansion is\MessageBreak
          of pattern\MessageBreak
          \@spaces #1\string####1#2\string####2\MessageBreak
          while \string####1 is not empty.\MessageBreak
          If this is the case, the expansion of \string\prjindex\space will be \string####1.\MessageBreak
          \string####1 will not contain underscores (\string_).\MessageBreak
          \string####2 can contain underscores.\MessageBreak
        }%
      }%
      &&&&%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\GetPrjindexPatternfork{%
    \def\GetPrjindexPatternfork##1&#1#2$&##2##3&&&&{##2}%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\GetPrjindexExtractfrompattern{%
    \def\GetPrjindexExtractfrompattern#1##1#2##2${%
      \ifx\relax##1\relax
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \fi
      {%
        \GenericError{(\string\prjindex)\space}{%
          Error on input line \the \inputlineno:\MessageBreak
          \string\prjindex\space is empty.\MessageBreak
          (\string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space is defined\MessageBreak
           \space somewhere in this document.)\@gobble
        }{Have a look at the comments in this document.}%
        {%
          \string\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined\space can extract the \string\prjindex\MessageBreak
          from \string\jobname's expansion only in case \string\jobname's expansion is\MessageBreak
          of pattern\MessageBreak
          \@spaces #1\string####1#2\string####2\MessageBreak
          while \string####1 is not empty.\MessageBreak
          If this is the case, the expansion of \string\prjindex\space will be \string####1.\MessageBreak
          \string####1 will not contain underscores (\string_).\MessageBreak
          \string####2 can contain underscores.\MessageBreak
        }%
      }%
      {\newcommand*\prjindex{##1}}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\prjprephrase\expandafter}%
\expandafter{\prjpostphrase}%
%%=====End of code for \GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined=====
% 
% This will define \prjindex depending on the expansion of \jobname
% while \jobname usually represents the name of the file used for
% initiating compilation:
%
% !!! I don't know whether, e.g., online-latex-plattforms like overleaf
% !!! invoke latex using the -jobname-option, which would lead to
% !!! the expansion of \jobname deviating from the name of the file
% !!! used for initiating compilation.
%
\GetPrjindexFromJobnameIfUndefined
%
% With subsequent preamble-commands you can, if you wish, fork depending on
% the expansion of \prjindex. But be aware that like \jobname \prjindex also
% holds only characters of catcode 12(other) and spaces of catcode 10(space).
% Therefore when storing a string in a temporary macro (this should, like
% \prjindex not be defined in terms of \long, which is the case with
% \def or \newcommand*) and \ifx-comparing that temporary macro to \prjindex,
% make sure that the definition of that temporary macro is "sanitized" by
% means of \@onelevel@sanitize before doing the \ifx-comparison.
%
%  \usepackage...
%  \usepackage...
%
\begin{document}%
\endinput
|
| Place whatsoever comments remarks and explanations and manuals you wish to place 
| here. They won't be processed because LaTeX ceases reading and processing this
| file when encountering \endinput.
```

Postamble.tex

```
\csname @\ifnum\inputlevel>1 second\else first\fi oftwo\endcsname
{%
  \end{document}%
}{%
  \xdef\inputlevel{\number\numexpr\inputlevel-1\relax}%
}%
```

Projekt_A_cp1.tex

```
%----------------------
\input{Preamble.tex}%
%----------------------
This is file \texttt{Projekt\string_A\string_cp1.tex}\par
This is the text in file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp1.tex}.\par
The file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp1.tex} invokes the file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp2.tex}:\par
\input{Projekt_\prjindex_cp2.tex}%
%----------------------
\input{Postamble.tex}%
%----------------------
```

Projekt_A_cp2.tex

```
%----------------------
\input{Preamble.tex}%
%----------------------
This is file \texttt{Projekt\string_A\string_cp2.tex}\par
This is the text in file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp2.tex}.\par
The file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp2.tex} invokes the file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp3.tex}:\par
\input{Projekt_\prjindex_cp3.tex}%
%----------------------
\input{Postamble.tex}%
%----------------------
```

Projekt_A_cp3.tex

```
%----------------------
\input{Preamble.tex}%
%----------------------
This is file \texttt{Projekt\string_A\string_cp3.tex}\par
This is the text in file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp3.tex}.\par
%----------------------
\input{Postamble.tex}%
%----------------------
```

Projekt_B_cp1.tex

```
%----------------------
\input{Preamble.tex}%
%----------------------
This is file \texttt{Projekt\string_B\string_cp1.tex}\par
This is the text in file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp1.tex}.\par
The file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp1.tex} invokes the file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp2.tex}:\par
\input{Projekt_\prjindex_cp2.tex}%
%----------------------
\input{Postamble.tex}%
%----------------------
```

Projekt_B_cp2.tex

```
%----------------------
\input{Preamble.tex}%
%----------------------
This is file \texttt{Projekt\string_B\string_cp2.tex}\par
This is the text in file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp2.tex}.\par
The file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp2.tex} invokes the file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp3.tex}:\par
\input{Projekt_\prjindex_cp3.tex}%
%----------------------
\input{Postamble.tex}%
%----------------------
```

Projekt_B_cp3.tex

```
%----------------------
\input{Preamble.tex}%
%----------------------
This is file \texttt{Projekt\string_B\string_cp3.tex}\par
This is the text in file \texttt{Projekt\string_\prjindex\string_cp3.tex}.\par
%----------------------
\input{Postamble.tex}%
%----------------------
```

This way each of the files `Projekt_A_cp1.tex`, `Projekt_A_cp2.tex`, `Projekt_A_cp3.tex`
respective each of the files `Projekt_B_cp1.tex`, `Projekt_B_cp2.tex`, `Projekt_B_cp3.tex`
can be used both for compiling "standalone" and for being invoked via `\input` or via `\include` by another file of the same project.

`Preamble.tex` can contain code where forking takes place depending on the
meaning of `\prjindex`, so things can be handled differently for different
projects within the same preamble-file.

Comment: thanks for your nice answer! As a "newbie", I will try to understand and absorb the new knowledge you mentioned...

Comment: @sun0727 In case you need explanation of how the code works/is intended to work, don't hesitate to ask. If you wish to switch to a communication-channel suitable for correspondence/dialogue but not focused that much on real-time communication, let me know. In the past the public usenet-newsgroup  comp.text.tex   was a good medium also for explaining/inspecting snippets of code. The communication is not necessarily real-time, but usually it takes place in a timely manner which is a good thing because one is not urged to reply immediately but can take some time for thinking about questions...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's the problem, but surely you need to make a change to your code: the argument to `\include` must *not* have the `.tex` extension.

```latex
\documentclass{book}

% why shouldn't this be elegant
\newcommand{\projectindex}{B}

\begin{document}

\include{chapter/Project_\projectindex_cp1}
\include{chapter/Project_\projectindex_cp2}
\include{chapter/Project_\projectindex_cp3}

\end{document}
```

Here's the terminal output when compiling this code

```
pdflatex sun
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./sun.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo)) (./sun.aux
(./chapter/Project_B_cp1.aux) (./chapter/Project_B_cp2.aux)
(./chapter/Project_B_cp3.aux)) (./chapter/Project_B_cp1.tex
Chapter 1.
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./chapter/Project_B_cp2.tex [2]
Chapter 2.
) [3] (./chapter/Project_B_cp3.tex [4]
Chapter 3.
) [5] (./sun.aux (./chapter/Project_B_cp1.aux) (./chapter/Project_B_cp2.aux)
(./chapter/Project_B_cp3.aux)) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/
public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmsl10.pfb>
Output written on sun.pdf (5 pages, 30009 bytes).
```

If I change to `\newcommand{\projectindex}{A}`, after two runs of LaTeX I get

```
pdflatex sun
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./sun.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo)) (./sun.aux
(./chapter/Project_A_cp1.aux) (./chapter/Project_A_cp2.aux)
(./chapter/Project_A_cp3.aux)) (./chapter/Project_A_cp1.tex
Chapter 1.
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./chapter/Project_A_cp2.tex [2]
Chapter 2.
) [3] (./chapter/Project_A_cp3.tex [4]
Chapter 3.
) [5] (./sun.aux (./chapter/Project_A_cp1.aux) (./chapter/Project_A_cp2.aux)
(./chapter/Project_A_cp3.aux)) )</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1
/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/
public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/pu
blic/amsfonts/cm/cmsl10.pfb>
Output written on sun.pdf (5 pages, 29893 bytes).
Transcript written on sun.log.
```

As you see, the expected files are included.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! It works well now!